# How do I filter query range objects by id primary_key? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can filter 5 articles latest by **slidenumber** field.?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    slidenumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(default="Mo ta")
    bodyrichtext= RichTextField(default="", null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as follow (descending) :

```
Article.objects.all().order_by('-slidenumber')[:5]
```

Ascending:

```
Article.objects.all().order_by('slidenumber')[:5]
```

You can use "pk" instead of "slidenumber" since it is a primary key

[Documentation for queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: No worries, do not forget to validate my answer so it can help other, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to order articles? I don't see a field that allows you to get "latest" or any time derived info?

```
      Article.objects.all().order_by('-slidenumber')
```

Comment: You don't need a field since Django provide a manager for that, also for the latest you can use slicing **[:5]** or whatever number suits you best

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the last five items by slicing with:

```
Article.objects.order_by('-slidenumber')[:5]
```

The `[:5]` will thus retrieve only the first five items for a `QuerySet` that ordered the `Article`s in descending order by `slidenumber`.